# Do WssId:s ever change?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, caml-query, term

To query for list items based on managed metadata field, first we query the `TaxonomyHiddenList` to get the `WssId` for the terms we search for. As the title says, does this WssId ever change or is it safe to cache indefinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use it for long time as long as that term is exist in the term stores. [as this property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfieldvalue.wssid(v=office.14).aspx) "A 32-bit integer that uniquely identifies the list item containing the taxonomy field in a list"

Here is good [explanation of the wssid](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/some-words-about-taxonomyfieldvalue-and-its-wssid-property/)

> When you assign value a TaxonomyField, an item is created for the
>   selected Term (or if there is already an item for the term, that item
>   is used)  in a hidden list called TaxonomyHiddenList in the root web
>   of the site. The WssId is the Id of that item in the
>   TaxonomyHiddenList .

Comment: Link above was broken, fixed: [explanation of the wssid](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/some-words-about-taxonomyfieldvalue-and-its-wssid-property/)